# MS Access Populating Continous form Sub-form via parameterized query dynamically

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I am working on an application that should allow user select a code from a list box, and this value should be passed as a parameter to a sub-form(continuous) which is tied to an SQL Query to populate the form with values returned from the query.

How do I tie the listbox on the parent form to the continuous form (child form) in such a way that a change in the listbox is registered in the subform and it(child form) is re-populated accordingly?

The code below is what I currently have in my Parent form to trigger the change in the subform. But I am still missing the bit where I trigger the reloading of the information in the subform with this.

storedproc

```
SELECT tblACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_LABEL, tblACCOUNTValue.[ACCOUNTVALUE_VALUE]
FROM ((tblUPS INNER JOIN tblProductUPS ON tblProductUPS.[PRODUCTUPS_UPS] = tblUPS.[UPS_CODE]) INNER JOIN tblACCOUNT ON tblUPS.UPS_ID = tblACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_UPSID) INNER JOIN tblACCOUNTValue ON tblACCOUNTVALUE.[ACCOUNTVALUE_ACCOUNTID]= tblACCOUNT.[ACCOUNT_ID]
WHERE TBLPRODUCTUPS.[PRODUCTUPS_PRODUCTID] =   (SELECT tblProductLevel.[PRODUCTLEVEL_ID] 

FROM  tblProductLevel WHERE tblProductLevel.[PRODUCTLEVEL_Code] IN ( [UPSIDS])

   );
```

This is a field in my sub-form which I would like to tie to my query as source of parameter for the query.

```
Public Property Let qString(unstring As String)
    If Not IsNull(unstring) And Len(unstring) > 0 Then
            Currentstring = unstring
    End If
End Property
```

The code below is code in my parent form I test connects directly to the Query that I created and passes the parameter directly to the query. However, since my sub-form is itself tied to the query, I need a way to get to the subform query and pass the information I need passed and invoke an update on the form afterwards.

```
  Private Sub LoadSubform(unspscstring As String)
On Error GoTo Err_LoadSubform_Change

            Dim dbs As Database
            Dim strSQL As String
            Dim strSelect  As String
            Dim strQueryName As String
            Dim qryDef As QueryDef
             Dim rst As Recordset
             Dim prmOne As DAO.Parameter

            Set dbs = CurrentDb
            'then we'll open up the query:
            Set qryDef = dbs.QueryDefs("spgetAttributeByUNSPSC")
            'Now we'll assign values to the query using the parameters option:
                'link your DAP.Parameters to the query
                'Set prmOne = qryDef.Parameters!param_one
                'prmOne = unspscstring
             qryDef.Parameters(0) = unspscstring
             'Now need to somehow trigger an update on the subform

            'Close all objects
            rst.Close
            qryDef.Close
            Set rst = Nothing
            Set qryDef = Nothing
Bye_LoadSubform_Change:
                     Exit Sub

Err_LoadSubform_Change:
Beep:                      MsgBox Error$, 16, "Select Failed"
                     Resume Bye_LoadSubform_Change

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this, against all the common ways of setting up a subform?

Comment: Are you really using a DAP? They went out of date sometime ago.

Comment: I am relatively new to ACCESS so I am possible unaware of the common ways to handle this sort of situation with subforms

Comment: You might like to look at the Northwind sample database, the code is not great, but it is very useful on ways to manage subforms. in general, you set the recordsource of a subform to a table name (not the best), a query or an SQL string. The subform is further limited by link child and master fields, so the query or sql can be quite simple.

Comment: Working from the above example, the record source would be the sql of spgetAttributeByUNSPSC and unspscstring could either be a reference to a control, a link field, or something added to the sql on load.

Comment: You could have:         Set Me.Recordset = rst ::
        'Close all objects ::
       '' rst.Close ::
        qryDef.Close ::
        ''Set rst = Nothing ::
        Set qdf = Nothing (where ::=new line)

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you mean yet. How do I create my continuous sub-form without tying it to the query? I ask this cause I suspect that by setting the source again, I remove the original record source the form was created with, is this correct?

Comment: Take a step back. What do you have in the main form? Is it a company? Do you wish to show accounts relating to the company in a subform? Are you working from MS Access tables?

Comment: Also, from my list box, I do not intend to allow just one item but multiple. I have an IN filter there in my query to allow for multiple checks so the reason why I want to gather the string and pass it to the subform for population

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15278/discussion-between-remou-and-kobojunkie)

Comment: This is products information. I wish to allow user to select a code, and based on that code, populate the subform with products that relate to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the listbox allows only one item, you can use the link child and master fields of the subform to do this.

```
Link Child Fields: ID; ListFieldMatch
Link Master Fields : ID; MyListBox
```

Alternatively, you can set the Record Source of the form object of the subform control in VBA:

```
sSQL = "SELECT ID,Stuff FROM Table WHERE ID=" & Me.MyNumericListBox
Me.MySubformControlName.Form.RecordSource = sSQL
```

Comment: what I thought to do was pass the parameter from my parent form and then have the child form take that and re-run the query. Is that not how it should be done?

Comment: I just now debugged that piece of the code. Please see new code and comment at the end.

Answer (score 0):

sSQL = "SELECT ID,Stuff FROM Table WHERE ID=" & Me.MyNumericListBox
Me.MySubformControlName.Form.RecordSource = sSQL

gives an error 2467 runtime error

"The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or does'nt exist.

Comment: Please improve the content formatting. Its unclear whats your solution